# iPhone Dev - Is it possible to load an app's mainWindow conditionally?

Tags: iphone, delegates, launch, mainwindow

Is it possible to code this sequence of events once an iPhone app has been launched?

- User launches application.
- AppDelegate.m checks if data is present in internal database.
- If yes, MainWindow.xib loads.
- If no, AnotherViewController.xib loads.

I've only seen app examples that load the MainWindow.xib without conditions.

If it is possible, which method in AppDelegate.m handles the logic? (applicationDidFinishLaunching? viewDidLoad?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to load the MainWindow conditionally.  Instead, load and show a viewController conditionally. This can be done in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: Got it! Here's the bit o' code I found that works well in applicationDidFinishLaunching:



 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *firsttime = [defaults stringForKey:@"firsttime"];
 if (firsttime == nil) {
  //first time firing code goes here
  NSLog(@"so, this is your first time, huh?");
  
  [defaults setObject:@"lasttime" forKey:@"firsttime"];